# Pandas - Calculate with datetime column with month and year only

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, streamlit

I struggle with a column in a dataframe with only should include month and year.

```
df["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datum"], format="%d.%m.%Y").dt.date
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum']).dt.strftime('%B-%Y')
```

I use this column as input for my streamlit app like this:

```
start_date = df["Month"].min()
end_date = df["Month"].max()

start, end = st.sidebar.slider("Label", start_date, end_date, (start_date, end_date))
```

Pandas seems to handle `dt.strftime('%B-%Y')` as a string with won´t allow me to do calculations with it.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

```
st.write(df["Month"].max() - df["Month"].min())
```

will also fail with the same error.

How can I use this specific format for calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use this specific format for calculations?

If need working with datetimes in python, pandas, it means cannot convert ouput to strings by `strftime`.

So need convert to custom string in `write` function:

```
df["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datum"], format="%d.%m.%Y").dt.date
#if need datetiems without times
#df["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datum"], format="%d.%m.%Y").dt.normalize()

#if need working with years and months only convert datetimes to month periods
#df["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datum"], format="%d.%m.%Y").dt.to_period('m')

start_date = df["Datum"].min()
end_date = df["Datum"].max()

start, end = st.sidebar.slider("Label", start_date.strftime('%B-%Y'), end_date.strftime('%B-%Y'), (start_date.strftime('%B-%Y'), end_date.strftime('%B-%Y')))
```